# Shrine validation of file extension does not allow Facebook image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, validation, shrine

I'm using Srhine for images in my project and Omniauth gems for logging via Google and Facebook.

My method of getting data from Omniauth provider is the standard one:

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.name = [auth.info.first_name, auth.info.last_name].join(" ")
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
      user.avatar_remote_url = auth.info.image
    end
  end
```

It allows me to login via Google and Facebook and get user data, name and image. I also have standard registration and possibility to update user.avatar so I wanted to validate the image so that it has a limited size and so that the extensions are also limited. I wrote the following validation in my Uploader class:

```
  Attacher.validate do
    validate_max_size 2*1024*1024
    # validate_extension %w[jpg jpeg png webp]
  end
```

The problem is that the validation of extension doesn't allow for registering new user via Facebook. In case of FB `auth.info.image` doesn't really return a link to an image like `'https://blabla/image.jpg'` but rather it creates a link which, when you paste it into the browser, results in direct download of the image to the hard drive. How can I write this validation so that it allows for the FB way of providing image to be saved? Or maybe how can I skip this validation in the Omniauth method?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom flag in `Shrine::Attacher` context hash before attaching the file:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.name = [auth.info.first_name, auth.info.last_name].join(" ")
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
    user.avatar_attacher.context[:omniauth] = true # <=== set the flag
    user.avatar_remote_url = auth.info.image
  end
end
```

Then in the `validate` block you can access it and skip extension validation if the flag is present:

```
Attacher.validate do
  validate_max_size 2*1024*1024
  validate_extension %w[jpg jpeg png webp] unless context[:omniauth]
end
```